# I already have an sprite sheet image, how can I get a plist file for cocos2D?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, sprite-sheet

I am learning how to animate a sprite, so the sprite sheet image is foud online. Problem is that I also need the plist file, which I don't have. I tried Zwoptex, but seems not work.

Any one got any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also go for the [Texture Packer](http://www.texturepacker.com/download/) to create the Sprite Sheets as well.

For Tutorial with Spritesheet from [Ray Wenderlich Demo](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2361/how-to-create-and-optimize-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d-with-texture-packer-and-pixel-formats), you can use to the Resources and play with the Sprite sheet Animations. It would help you to learn making the Animations.

Regarding already created sprite sheet you need the plist from who-so-ever have created the Sprite Sheet

**OR**

you need to create the chunks using Photoshop and create a newer Sprite Sheet.

All I can suggest these options.

Comment: Yes I at last have to split them into many chuncks. Though I don't know anything about Photoshop.

Comment: okay. Photoshop is easy to use it. You can get many tutorials just by googling. :)

Answer (score 3):

Zwoptex works just fine. It does output a .plist file for cocos2d perfectly.

I am using the Mac version. Go to Publish settings, and there you should see the output location for the .plist file. Now, when ready, click Publish. It will output both the texture and the coordinates in the locations that you set in Settings. And it works.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear. The sprite sheet already has many small sprites which are sequences of an animation. I need the plist file reflect them.

Comment: Sequences for an animation? But it should still work just fine. If you name your sequences in a proper way (anim1.png,anim2.png,anim3.png), it should be rather easy to use them for your animation.

Answer (score 0):

On thing you CAN do if you already have a png or gif file is to download something like Paint.NET, make it transparent similar to this link [here](http://forums.getpaint.net/index.php?/topic/12196-making-backgrounds-of-images-transparent/). Then, you can use Texture Packer as mentioned above to split the sprites. Texture Packer can see the images, but only when it is transparent.

After that, you can then recreate the sprite sheet.